# Capture a string that doesn't start with a certain word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying capture a certain string using preg_match. I'm trying to capture all strings that doesn't start with the word (what) and ends with (is my name), however, my regex is not capturing the name for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
$string = "alex is my name";
if (preg_match("~(?<!what) is my name~", $string, $match)) {
print_r($match);
} //end of if (preg_match("~(?<!what) is my name~", $string, $match))
```

**Result:**

Array ( [0] => is my name )

**Need Result:**

Array ( [0] => alex ) ( [1] => is my name )

Comment: can not you just explode? explode('is my name', $string); "is my name" will be always the same right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative lookahead instead of negative lookbehind..

```
preg_match("~^(?!what\b)(\w+) is my name\b~", $string, $match)
```

or

```
preg_match("~\b(?!what\b)(\w+) is my name\b~", $string, $match)
```

Replace the last `\b` with end of the line anchor `$` if necessary.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xW2oI3/1)

Comment: Without the (^) it captures (hat) as the name if the string is (what is my name). I would rather not have the (^) because what if users submit something like (so what is my name) or something like that.

Comment: I meant WITHOUT the (^), not WITH. Sorry that was typo, please reread the above if you've already read it and it didn't make sense.

Comment: What I don't understand is how was it possible for it to capture (hat) as the name without the (^). How did that happen?

Comment: `(?!what\b)` checks the for the match won't be preceded by `what` without `^`, `(?!what\b)(\w+)` should match `hat` in `what` because the string `hat` is not preceded by `what`